# Change specific index of string, padding if necessary

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string called `indicators`, that the original developer of this application used to store single characters to indicate certain components of a model. I need to change the 7th character in the string, which I tried to do with the following code:

```
indicators[6] = "R"
```

The problem, I discovered quickly, was that the string is not always 7 characters long. For example, I have one set of values with `U  2`, that I need to convert to `U  2  R` (adding an additional space after the 2). Is there an easy way to force character count with Ruby?

Comment: can you clairfy more? you say 'I need to change the 7th char in the string' which would be indexed with `indicators[6]`, but the rest of your question is confusing me

Comment: @LukeP, Sorry, I've updated with the correct index. The issue is that I need the 7th char to be "R". If the string isn't 7 characters long that add enough spacing to make it 7 characters long. For example `U  2` is 4 characters, so it needs to result in `U  2  R` to ensure "R" is at the 7th character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`String.ljust(integer, padstr=' ')`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-ljust)

> If `integer` is greater than the length of [the receiver], returns a new String of
>   length `integer` with [the return value] left justified and padded with `padstr`;
>   otherwise, returns [an unmodified version of the receiver].

```
indicators = indicators.ljust(7)
indicators[6] = "R"
```